# Dependent vs Independent events (Conditional Probability using a pair of dice)

Tags: conditional-probability, independence

I am watching [this video on YouTube](https://youtu.be/eSBl_3B24aE) to understand dependent and independent events and conditional probability. The example author uses is of a pair of dice.

There are 2 dice, Red and Green, let's say:

- A is an event where Red die $\ge 4$
- B is an event where number on Green die is larger than the number in event A.

**then are A and B independent ?**

[image]

$$P(A|B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$$

$$P(B) = 15/36,   P(A \cap B) = 3/36 \implies P(A|B) = 1/5$$

Now And and B independent only if $$P(A|B) = P(A)$$

and probability of Red die being greater than 4 is just $1/2$

$$ P(A | B) = P(A) \implies 1/5 = 1/2$$

which is not true, hence A and B are dependent events.

**MY PROBLEM:** I can't understand the reasoning. Practically speaking,  a roll of Green die and roll of Red die are completely independent. One can not not affect the other. If Green die got 3 e.g. it can't affect the Red die to have or not to have 3.  Then how they are dependent like author proved ?

Comment: "B is an event where Green die is larger than event A." doesn't make sense. The *event* in A is "the red die is greater than 4" ... If the green die is showing a 5, say, how can you compare that with event A? one outcome is a number, the other is something that might happen; it's not a number. Do you you mean to compare the value on the green die to the value on the red die?

Comment: I edited the post to be clearer.  I am comparing numbers on the dice.  Event B is when number on green die is larger than the number in event A (red die $\ge 4$)

Comment: Your present definitions don't match the probabilities in your question. If B is the event "the number on the green die is greater than the number on the red die" *that* would have P(B) = 15/36.

Comment: Honestly I don't get your question ;(

Comment: Your question asserts a value for P(B), it says that it's 15/36, right?

Comment: Yes. Professor in video adds the probabilities to get the number *15*. What if event $A$ means red die has value $\ge 1$,  then $B$ will have $6$ values.  Next, what if event $A$ means red die has value $\ge 2$ then $B$ has $5$ values. Then  $B = 6 +5 = 11$. He adds like that and makes $B = 15$.  is it wrong ?

Comment: Yes, that works great if you define B as the proportion of times the green die is greater than the red die. However, *your* definition of B relates to the case where the red die is already $\geq 4$, so you can't just compare it to a situation where the red die shows $1$; you're counting cases that don't match your own definition of $B$. I expect you haven't quite correctly shown the situation.

Comment: I watched the video again and can't figure out if I have typed something wrong in my OP.  have added the screenshot of video.  Can you please point out where I am wrong

Comment: Right in the first sentence of the image -- it defines B exactly as I suggested, which is not what you wrote.

Comment: Thanks. This removes the confusion we had. My original question is still in the air, how come events are dependent  when roll one die is in no way affected by the other. Independent dice and hence independent events.  But he proved they are dependent.